# Data missing from ephermal device

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I was working on live AWS EC2 instace which has ephermal disk attached to it.
Disk /dev/xvda: 8 GiB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x55bca5c1

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/xvda1 *     2048 16777182 16775135   8G 83 Linux

Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 442.4 GiB, 475000000000 bytes, 927734375 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

============
/dev/nvme0n1 was mounted on partition /var/www/html
I created an image from this instance. After i created the image, i launched another instance from it.

Now, after this, the data that was there on ephermal disk is not visible on live server, and it is not available on live site as well.
Please suggest , how can i get that data on ephermal disk.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not make a lot of sense.   Ephemeral means "lasting only a short time" - ie the type of disk you are storing data on is not designed to persist.  If you want the data to persist you need a different type of storage or to save it elsewhere and reload it.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/instance-store-vs-ebs/ states "Some Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instance types come with a form of directly attached, block-device storage known as the instance store. The instance store is ideal for temporary storage, because the data stored in instance store volumes is not persistent through instance stops, terminations, or hardware failures.

For data you want to retain longer, or if you want to encrypt the data, use Amazon Elastic Block Store (Amazon EBS) volumes instead. EBS volumes preserve their data through instance stops and terminations, can be easily backed up with EBS snapshots, can be removed from one instance and reattached to another, and support full-volume encryption. " and this would seem to be the answer to your question.

Comment: Yes, i meant instance store. Server was rebooted and i lost all the data on instance store.In any way, can i recover the data? I have image of the AMI

Comment: Probably not, and definitely not without help from Amazon - http://aws.amazon.com/instance-help/ (Search for "data recovery" on that link.)

Comment: Data on the ephemeral disk is temporary. If it's gone, it's gone, no-one can recover it. If you need persistence of the data on the disk you need to do it yourself. You can use them for things like databases, but you need to do something like 1) Regularly backup the data to EBS / S3 2) Sync to another database in another AWS (slightly risky if it's on an instance store too)